# Epson WF-2630, driver installed, can't choose draft option and print on both sides

Tags: drivers, gnome, printing

As the title said, I've got this strange issues. 
I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 and I'm using an Epson All in One printer Wf-2630  via WiFi. 
I installed the .deb package from the [Official EPSON Downlaod center](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=IT&CN2=&DSCMI=60612&DSCCHK=f1245c6b9b80beaa4d150cd8a54bae773d83ca18). Then installed it on Settings>Printer>Gear icon>printer details>choose from database> Epson WF-2630 driver

But I still can't use draft option and both sides printing. 
It will be great if I will have this kind of option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a lot of settings in the proprietary driver. probably you didn/t find it. Did you click `more` in the options.

Comment: Here's what I've got in printer options: http://i.imgur.com/DAjyquH.png

Comment: This doesn't look like proprietary driver options.

Comment: Look how it should look https://itmages.ru/image/view/6045572/687e58de

Comment: Select "Task Options" at the left.

Comment: I tried to click "Impostazioni Pagina" on the left (I'm italian, I think you are talking about that when you said task option) and it does nothing.